# Property changes in the observable items in my collection is not recognized by XAML binding the entire item

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

How do I get the item updates in my collection of observable items to be recognized if I bind to the entire item?

I have a class `Codec` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class Codec : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private bool _isEnabled;

  public bool IsEnabled
  {
    get => _isEnabled;
    set
    {
      _isEnabled = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();  // Raises PropertyChanged
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

I then have a view-model with an observable collection of `Codec`:s.

```
public class CodecsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollection<Codec> Codecs { get; }

  ...
}
```

And a view that lists the codecs, where the accessibility string of the container is bound to each individual `Codec` item:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Codecs}">
  <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackLayout
        AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource CodecPresenter}}">
        ...
      </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
  </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
<CollectionView>
```

When I change the `IsEnabled` status of an individual `Codec` item, I would expect that the update triggers a new call to my `CodecPresenter` converter so that the  `AutomationProperties.Name` property gets updated. However, it is not.

It does not help to manually raise `PropertyChanged` on the `Codecs` collection. Is there any way I can signal to the `AutomationProperties.Name` binding that the item contents have changed although the item (reference) remains the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `Self` property to your model

```
public Codec Self {
    get {
        return this;
    }
}

public bool IsEnabled
  {
    get => _isEnabled;
    set
    {
      _isEnabled = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();  
      OnPropertyChanged(Self);
    }
  }
```

and then bind to it

```
AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Self, Converter={StaticResource CodecPresenter}}">
```

idea originated from this [post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65678/how-to-get-inotifypropertychanged-for-the-whole-object) on the Xamarin Forums